# html-css weird line order

Tags: html, css, css-grid, grid-layout

Well, I am completely a beginner to front end developing so I have maybe a dumb question.For some reason my `div`s in another `div`s appear a way more out than the normal one. Because I can't explain it so good with words I am going to post my code both from `html` and `css`. Any ideas on how to fix that?

[image: The problem is in the blue text]

```css
.footer {
 grid-column:1/-1;
 background-color: white;
}
company-name {
 font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
 color:black;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
.footer > div > a{
 font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
 color:black;
 font-size: 1em;
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
 <div class="company-name">The Spooky Side © 2019</div>
  <div class="contact"><a href=""><br>contact</a></div>
  <div class="privacy-policies"><a href=""><br>-privacy policies</a></div>
  <div class="cookies"><a href=""><br>-cookies</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need to use div for that, use one <p> (parent of all) and use <span></span> for each child of the <p> or ethen just a simple <a> for each child (with the class on the <a> directly.

Comment: seems both html and css are incomplete , there is no footer class in html which you provided and no css details for contact, privacy-policies and cookies classes

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the whole page? Or at least the whole footer?

Comment: I made an update and i add the footer class that i forgot. Yea it seems incomplete because i want to first align all text in oreder to continue with contact, privacy-policies and cookies :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used flex to center and put in the same height the content of the footer.

I have also used > to select all the dives inside the footer.

Try this. ;)

```
<footer>
        <div class="name">The Spooky Side © 2019</div>
        <div class="contact"><a href=""><br>contact</a></div>
        <div class="privacy-policies"><a href=""><br>-privacy policies</a></div>
        <div class="cookies"><a href=""><br>-cookies</a></div>
</footer>
```

```css
/*F O O T E R */
.footer {
    width:100%;
    display:flex; 
    justify-content: center; /*horizontal align*/
    align-items: center; /*vertical align*/

    background-color: white;
}

.footer > div {
    margin: 0 10px
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    color:black;
}

company-name {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.footer > div > a{
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration:none; 
}
```

If you want to know more about the flex property:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/